# Why are there 2 ssh services?

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, centos, openssh

I just downloaded a virtual appliance built on Debian and went to enable sshd but saw this:

[image]

What is the difference between ssh.service and ssh@.service and where is sshd? I checked and openssh-server is installed.

I more familiar with centos so I'm guess Debian calls the daemon ssh but redhat calls it sshd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is traditional `sshd` service, the other is socket-activated `sshd`. You can find more by investigation of the unit file itself: `/lib/systemd/system/ssh@.service` and `/lib/systemd/system/ssh.socket` (on Debian, on Fedora and RHEL, prepend `/usr/`).

About the difference, it is just naming. It must call also `sshd` binary as CentOS.

For further reading, in [Red Hat bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=963268) is described the creation of such "service" exactly for `ssh` (beware of the naming, Debian uses `ssh` instead of `sshd`, probably everywhere).

Comment: The services are in `/lib/systemd/system/` for both Debian and Ubuntu (at least as of Debian 9 and Ubuntu 16).